# Reading Pixels in WebGL 2 as Float values

Tags: opengl-es, particles, glreadpixels, webgl2

I need to read the pixels of my framebuffer as float values.
My goal is to get a fast transfer of lots of particles between CPU and GPU and process them in realtime. For that I store the particle properties in a floating point texture.

Whenever a new particle is added, I want to get the current particle array back from the texture, add the new particle properties and then fit it back into the texture (this is the only way I could think of to dynamically add particles and process them GPU-wise).

I am using WebGL 2 since it supports reading back pixels to a `PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER` target. I test my code in Firefox Nightly. The code in question looks like this:

```
// Initialize the WebGLBuffer
this.m_particlePosBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, this.m_particlePosBuffer);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, null);
...
// In the renderloop, bind the buffer and read back the pixels
gl.bindBuffer(gl.PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, this.m_particlePosBuffer);
gl.readBuffer(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0); // Framebuffer texture is bound to this attachment
gl.readPixels(0, 0, _texSize, _texSize, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, 0);
```

I get this error in my console:

```
TypeError: Argument 7 of WebGLRenderingContext.readPixels could not be converted to any of: ArrayBufferView, SharedArrayBufferView.
```

But looking at the current WebGL 2 Specification, this function call should be possible. Using the type `gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE` also returns this error.
When I try to read the pixels in an ArrayBufferView (which I want to avoid since it seems to be way slower) it works with the format/type combination of `gl.RGBA` and `gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE` for a `Uint8Array()` but not with `gl.RGBA` and `gl.FLOAT` for a `Float32Array()` - this is as expected since it's documented in the WebGL Specification.

I am thankful for any suggestions on how to get my float pixel values from my framebuffer or on how to otherwise get this particle pipeline going.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using this extension?

```
var ext = gl.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float');
```

Answer (score 0):

The gl you have is webgl1,not webgl2.Try:

```
var gl = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('webgl2');
```

Answer (score -1):

In WebGL2 the syntax for glReadPixel is

```
void gl.readPixels(x, y, width, height, format, type, ArrayBufferView pixels, GLuint dstOffset);
```

so

```
let data = new Uint8Array(gl.drawingBufferWidth * gl.drawingBufferHeight * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels, 0);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels